# deb package dependency versions a bit useless?

Tags: package-management, deb, versions

I'm creating a deb package for the first time (using CPack, but I don't think that's relevant), and I'm confused by dependent package versioning.  My application depends on 2 Boost libraries and I need a minimum of v1.71, so I *thought* I could just use this string:

```
"libboost-program_options (>= 1.71), libboost-log (>= 1.71)"
```

But it turns out those packages have the **version in their name!**  So I have to use this string in order to get the package to install at all:

```
"libboost-program_options1.71.0 (>= 1.71), libboost-log1.71.0  (>= 1.71)"
```

Which renders the minimum versioning specification useless.  So now if someone has v1.73 of the libraries installed, which would be perfectly fine, `apt` would fail to meet the dependencies!

How do 'real' package maintainers solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use meta packages `libboost-program-options-dev` and `libboost-log-dev`.

They will pull the relevant  `libboost-program_optionsx.xx.x`.

So the depends line will look this way:

```
libboost-program-options-dev (>= 1.71), libboost-log-dev (>= 1.71)
```

Comment: It's not great as it pulls in the source for the libraries, but it's certainly better than nothing.

Comment: The problem is that there is no meta package for those without `dev`. There is `libboost-all` or something like that. But it pulls much more than you need.

Comment: @cmannett85 Another option is not to specify the version at all. All 20.04 releases will have 1.71+ versions anyway.